# Change Minimal master page Links and Options

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, master-page

In SharePoint 2013 Business Intelligence site I give access to some users as `Visitor` and I want them to not see some options and links like `NewFeed`, `SkyDrive`, `Follow` , `Settings` etc.

How can I hide these links and options to them?

Should I change the minimal masterpage in SharePoint Designer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deactivate "Follow documents" feature in your site to remove Share and Follow links.

For SuiteLinks you can comment the following delegate control

```
<SharePoint:DelegateControl id="ID_SuiteLinksDelegate" ControlId="SuiteLinksDelegate" runat="server" />
```

For others you may need to add css/js, following link should help:
[SharePoint 2013 Top links – Name, ID and How to Hide them](http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/08/12/sharepoint-2013-top-links-name-id-and-how-to-hide-them/)

Comment: Thanks.I have 2 question.1) Where I should place that javascript code? 2)Is it possible to not render them by change minimal master page?

Comment: 1) You can place the JavaScript code in MasterPage html file.. 2) Try it :)